# Twitter authentication with child window return closed true while window opend

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

## **The Information**

I am trying to authenticate twitter in our page but facing some issue when I open child window for authenticate, its return Window.closed = true while the window is opened **[Twitter OAuth2 in popup window]**

---

$scope.authUrl= **"https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=https#############2&response_type=code&client_id=###############&scope=tweet.read%20users.read%20like.write%20tweet.write%20offline.access&code_challenge=challenge&code_challenge_method=plain&state=state**

```
$scope.childWindow = window.open($scope.authUrl, "twitter", "width=600,height=500");

setInterval(function(){
   $scope.checkWindow();
],500);

$scope.checkWindow = function(){
//when window closed
 if($scope.childWindow.closed){
  //Do something
 }
}
```

## **The problem**

I want to do something when window closed but having issue while the window is opened **$scope.childWindow**  return closed = true.

---

## **The question**

How to prevent **$scope.childWindow.closed** return true if window is still open? I want **$scope.childWindow.closed** value false till window not closed

**Thank you in advance, any answer is appreciated!**